# Swift2で絵文字キーボードを作ろうと思っていますがエリアの高さの設定がわからない

Tags: swift

キーボードを作ってみたいと思っています。 
そこで、キーボードのエリアの高さを調整したいと思っています。

具体的には候補表示用に、1行分、広げたいのです。

どのようにしたら、高さを調整できますか？

```
let portraitHeight:CGFloat = 256.0
let landscapeHeight:CGFloat = 203.0
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    if (self.view.frame.size.width == 0 || self.view.frame.size.height == 0) {
        return
    }
    inputView!.removeConstraint(heightConstraint!)
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let screenH = screenSize.height;
    let screenW = screenSize.width;
    let isLandscape =  !(self.view.frame.size.width == screenW * ((screenW < screenH) ? 1 : 0) + screenH * ((screenW > screenH) ? 1 : 0))
    NSLog(isLandscape ? "Screen: Landscape" : "Screen: Potriaint");
    if (isLandscape) {
        heightConstraint!.constant = landscapeHeight;
        inputView!.addConstraint(heightConstraint!)
    } else {
        heightConstraint!.constant = self.portraitHeight;
        inputView!.addConstraint(heightConstraint!)
    }
    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}


override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  

    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()  

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")  
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)  


    bunPrint()  
    btnTitle1()  
    fFastBoot = false  

}
```

上記ソースはNSLogで落ちます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

カスタムキーボードの高さを変えるのはAutoLayoutでやる必要があります。
（他の一般のビューと違って、AutoLayout以外の方法では、実際の高さが変化しません）

公式のドキュメントでは下記の中ほどに書いてあります。

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

いろいろ注意点がありまして、設定するのは`viewDidAppear`以降のタイミングでなければなりません。
（それ以前に同じコードで設定しても無視されます。`viewDidAppear`以降ならいつでも任意の高さに変更することが可能です。）

もっとも簡単な例でいうと、下記のように、初期のコードに`viewDidAppear`メソッドをオーバーライドして、高さを設定するAutoLayoutの制約を付けるコードを追加します。
下記の例だと、高さを500ポイント（通常の高さの約２倍）に設定しています。

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 500)
        view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
下記コード実装してみました。

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 500)
        view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }

しかし、どうも変化しません。トリガーが必要でしょうか？
Swift2で何か変わっているのでしょうか？
ドキュメントとにらめっこしてますが、答えが出ません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint のパラメータ multiplier の値を、0 ではなく、1 にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: multiplier の値 を変えてみましたが、変化なしです。
お助けいただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: addConstraint( ) など制約関連のメソッドですが、inputViewを使わずに、self.view で呼び出すよう全て統一してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)ということでしょうか？これもダメです。override func viewWillTransitionToSizeというのは関係ありますか？

Comment: そうです、self.view.addConstraint(...)等のことです。ですが今はひとまず、キーボードの高さを変更するコードのみを試すために、新規プロジェクトを Single View Application テンプレートで作成し、Custom Keyboard のターゲットを追加して、自動生成されたデフォルトの KeyboardViewController クラスに、こちらの回答にある override func viewDidAppear 部分のコードのみを追加し、Runしてみてはいかがでしょうか。こちらの回答のコードでキーボード高さが調整可能であることが、ご確認いただけると思います。起動時に、キーボードが、設定通りの高さで表示されるはずです。他のコードと組み合わせることでこれが思うように働かなくなる場合には、その点をより具体的に尋ねる質問を新たに投稿してみるといいかもしれません。

Comment: 最小限のテストコードは正しく動きました。作り直して、今の機能をすこしづつ戻して問題箇所を潰していきます。ありがとうございました。