# Swift3 Keyboard Extensionの高さが変わらない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

以前同じ質問をしましたが、再度iOSソフトウェアキーボードを作成しようとしたところ、キーボードの高さが変えられません。
下記リンクのの質問の答えを参考にしたり、ネットで英文情報を検索しました（結果、下記リンクと同じ答えだった・英語力の問題はあるかもしれません）が、うまくいきません。
いくつかの場所に`print(self.view.frame.size)`を追加しheightを見ても変更が反映されていません。

最低限の機能（プロジェクト作成、KeyboardExtension追加、下記viewDidAppearをオーバーライドし回転時の高さ変更コード追加）をしましたが、現環境では高さ変更が効きません。
追加したコードは、下記の質問にお答えをいただいたコードを追加したのみです。

[Swift2で絵文字キーボードを作ろうと思っていますがエリアの高さの設定がわからない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14248/swift2%E3%81%A7%E7%B5%B5%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AE%E9%AB%98%E3%81%95%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

キーボードの高さを500にするため追加した最低限のコード

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 500)
        view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```

仕様が変更になったのでしょうか？
ただし、下記を見る限り変更はないように思います。
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html

参照情報でもいいので、ご回答いただければ幸いです。

環境は以下の通りです。
iOS10.3.3 / Swift3 / XCode8.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プロジェクトを削除してMacを再起動し、キーボードを削除してシュミレーターも再起動し、再度プロジェクトを作成したところ、タイトルの問題が解決しました。

ただし、なぜこの現象が起きたのか不明なのと、作成済みキーボードでは問題継続中なので、原因は究明が必要ですが、タイトルの現象は解決しましたので、質問についてはクローズいたします。

ありがとうございました。